# How to disable PostBack while still firing OnClick events associated with ASP.NET web forms app

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms Page wherein a user opens a picture in an ImageButton Web Control. The user can interact with the ImageButton through clicking on different spots. In the C# code where the OnClick events associated with the ImageButton and various other Button Web Controls, there are a few dozen global variables of the types: int, float, string, and bool. Most OnClick functions   update these variables and continually add to some of the int variables.

My problem is that my C# variables are not being remembered.
I got some  answers to a question about remembering the variables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560999/update-counter-when-user-clicks-an-asp-net-web-app-imagebutton). Most of the answers mention saving variables in more persistent forms to hold against **PostBack**. It looks like PostBack is what is causing the variables to not be remembered. There is also the additional problem that the ImageButton always gets set to its default location in its CSS container and the user has to find their place in the ImageButton ( I attached a picture depicting how the picture is displayed) , also caused by the PostBack.

Is there any way I can disable **PostBack**, while still firing the OnClick events?

What might help is the fact that I only want to load this particular page of the web application while the user needs to use it. The variables only exist on the webpage, so I have no need for a database.

[image]

Comment: A `PostBack` in WebForms is simply a standard HTTP Post (like a form being submitted), hence the entire page is refreshed. So unless you implement some form of persistence (like in the link you provided), that behavior is expected. If you don't want a Page refresh/reload, look into [Ajax implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5331986/304683). Hth.

Comment: I think the answers in the link can help me with the variables, but how do I keep the ImageButton from moving and flickering on PostBack?

Comment: Again, a Postback refreshes the page, so if you are sticking to it, then you'll have to persist _everything_ you want to be persisted, including whatever front end artifacts you require and "rebuild" them. "Persistence" can be server side or even client side (web storage), but if you're going for the latter, then just go further with Ajax.

Comment: Eric, your question isn't broad (in fact the answer is no - you cannot disable postback and expect page.control event handlers to be supported by the framework), but given the question - to address this is to essentially explain (discuss) and/or point to reference material on what ASP.NET Webform Application are - concepts like Partial Page Updates, ViewStates, Control States, Webform Page and Control Lifecycles.